# php reading textfile word by word

Tags: php, text-files

I have a textfile which contain words like that:

```
Yigit Ozkavci 19
Efe Ozkavci 18
Yeni Bar 35
.
.
.
```

They are exist in database and also in textfile, what I want to do is to read those datas and get them in seperate variables, I know how to read a file line by line, but with a foreach loop can I echo them seperately and send data to another php file ?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just make use of [`file()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) ? It reads entire content inside an array.

```
<?php
$arr = file('yourfile.txt');
```

You can access `Yigit Ozkavci 19` by `echo $arr[0];` and others so on...

If you want to process it... you can just run it on foreach like this

```
foreach($arr as $val)
{
echo strtoupper($val); // Just a demonstration ..
}
```

Comment: [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/str_word_count) or [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) may help if this is not sufficient.

Comment: Okay, thanks for that, actually both using foreach loop and explode() function works for me, solved :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Get a file into an array.  In this example we'll go through HTTP to get
// the HTML source of a URL.
$lines = file('http://www.example.com/');

// Loop through our array, show HTML source as HTML source; and line numbers too.
foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
    echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . $line . "<br />\n";
}
?>
```

Hope This Helps :)